# Add another monitor to VirtualBox while running?

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors

Is it possible to add another monitor to a VM running in VirtualBox without shutting down the VM? I work on a laptop during the day and go between having a second monitor and not having one.

What's the best way to switch between a single and dual monitor config quickly without shutting down?

Comment: You need to shutdown a vm to add/remove hardware.

Comment: As a reference point, VMWare allows you to add a second monitor in a hot-swap manner. Tested on VMWare Fusion + Win8.1 host OS. Just plug in the 2nd monitor in full screen mode and full screen spans both monitors now! VirtualBox needs to improve itself...

Comment: Yep, VMware is top notch!

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't just adjust the (virtual) hardware without shutting down, one thing you could try is using Remote Desktop Multi-Monitor configuration. This way you just need to reconnect the RDP connection when you disconnect and let the guest operating system adjust to your new monitor configuration:

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vrde-multiconnection

Comment: This means I am effectively doing my work in an RDP connection to a local VM, correct?

Comment: @jocull - that is correct